# The data i sorted in MySQL is order by unique constraint not primary key

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

i will get straight to the point and i hope my question is understandable because my english is not very well. So, i use mysql 8.0.23 and i have table like this

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id_mhs | int | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| nama | varchar(45) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| npm | char(8) | YES | UNI | NULL |  |
| j_kelamin | enum('L','P') | YES |  | NULL |  |
| t_lahir | date | YES |  | NULL |  |
| alamat | varchar(50) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| kota | varchar(45) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| telepon | varchar(12) | YES | UNI | NULL |  |
| email | varchar(50) | YES | UNI | NULL |  |

And i showed the data like this

| id_mhs | nama | npm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AA Aditya A | 51411136 |
| 2 | A Aditya A | 51412371 |
| 3 | A Dimas A | 51411111 |
| 4 | A Faisal Dimas | 51411112 |
| 5 | A Faridah Nur | 51411113 |

The result was right but when i tried this query `mysql> select id_mhs, npm from mahasiswa limit 10;`

| id_mhs | npm |
| --- | --- |
| 28 | 51411036 |
| 47 | 51411054 |
| 83 | 51411100 |
| 84 | 51411101 |
| 85 | 51411102 |

The result was sorted by npm not with id_mhs, same result when i use order by npm, then i tried to remove unique constraint in column npm and the data sorted with id_mhs. So, column with unique constraint & string data type will prioritized to sort data than primary key?

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'default' order in a sql table, you have to use ORDER BY to order what you want.

Good way is to have, as you do have, an unique id as unique index (primary key is nice) to retrieve your 'default' order, but you have to sepcify by 'ORDER BY id'